Iterating over two lists just uses the first five members and others are not used
I'm so sorry, I couldn't simplify the sample (I may make it less by your hints).
This is my code.
The base view is: I have around 100 IPs and 10 tokens in real-world example (but the sample, I intentionally added 28 tokens). Each token can be used 4 times per minute (in fact, it should be used each 25 seconds).
Each IP should use one token only and send a GET request to the url and finishes it. If IP 1.1.1. used token a, then it should not use token b anymore, and the next iteration should go to IP 2.2.2.2.
A problem I have is: in the real I have 10 tokens and I add sleep(5) to make at least 25 seconds gap between the first and the fifth, but the issue with my current code is:
it uses first token, second one, third one, fourth one and fifth one. Then since the last use of token a was 25 seconds ago, then it again uses token a. While I except that all tokens should be used.
In my current code, the issue is if I have more than 5 tokens, I'll have this problem.
I know one way is to reduce the sleep value, but if I increase the tokens in the future, I should change the sleep value too.
Would you please help me?
tokens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
dbs = [{'token': x, 'time': None} for x in tokens]
client_ips = [{'ip': x['ip'], 'desc': x['desc']} for x in clients]

thirty_days_ago = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=days)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
requests_response_list = []
checked_ips = set()
for ip in client_ips:
    for db in dbs:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if ip['ip'] in checked_ips:
            continue
        if db['time']:
            elapsed_time = (now - db['time']).total_seconds()
            if elapsed_time < 25:
                continue
        print(f"IP is {ip['ip']}, Token: {db['token']}.")
        response = requests.get(
            url=f"http://my.url.com/ip_addresses/{ip['ip']}",
            headers={
                'accept': 'application/json',
                'x-apikey': db['token'],
            }
        ).json()['data']['attributes']
        for report in response:
            # report['date'] is a timestamp value, so I convert it to a date Y-m-d.
            date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(report['date']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            if thirty_days_ago <= date:
                requests_response_list.append({
                    'ip': ip['ip'],
                    'date': date,
                })
        db['time'] = now
        checked_ips.add(ip['ip'])
        sleep(5)
        break


date = date doesn't seem right. I'm guessing it should be date = report['date']

I don't really understand what you're trying to do. But you have the times associated only with tokens, not with IPs. And nothing relates the IPs with tokens.

@Barmar I updated the date

@Barmar I'm going to use one IP for one token and then go to another one.

I would recommend making something simple that works first and then making it complicated, instead of making something complicated and then asking a question that feels really hard to answer because it's not clear what the problem you're trying to solve is.

I think you are facing this issue not exactly related to the timing but how the tokens are being used. you need to control the rate at which tokens are used independently of the sleep interval and ensure that every token is used before reusing any. right?
If that is the case, using a round robin way to cycle through the token might help.
The question is a little confusing to understand. I am assuming a lot. Try this,
import datetime
from time import sleep
import requests

# a random dict created for the example purpose. replace with your own.
clients = [{'ip': '1.1.1.1', 'desc': 'ones'},
           {'ip': '2.2.2.2', 'desc': 'twos'}, 
           {'ip': '3.3.3.3', 'desc': '3s'}, 
           {'ip': '4.4.4.4', 'desc': '4s'}, 
           {'ip': '5.5.5.5', 'desc': '5s'}, 
           {'ip': '6.6.6.6', 'desc': '6s'}, 
           {'ip': '7.7.7.7', 'desc': '7s'}, 
           {'ip': '8.8.8.8', 'desc': '8s'}, 
           {'ip': '9.9.9.9', 'desc': '9s'}, 
           {'ip': '10.10.10.10', 'desc': '10s'}, 
           {'ip': '11.11.11.11', 'desc': '11s'}, ]

tokens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
dbs = [{'token': x, 'time': None} for x in tokens]
client_ips = [{'ip': x['ip'], 'desc': x['desc']} for x in clients]

days = 30  # assuming this is what you meant by days=days on the next line
thirty_days_ago = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=days)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

requests_response_list = []
checked_ips = set()
token_index = 0  # Start with the first token

for ip in client_ips:
    # use the token index to retrieve the db for operation.
    db = dbs[token_index]

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if ip['ip'] in checked_ips:
        continue
    if db['time']:
        elapsed_time = (now - db['time']).total_seconds()
        if elapsed_time < 25:
            continue
    print(f"IP is {ip['ip']}, Token: {db['token']}.")
    response = requests.get(
        url=f"http://my.url.com/ip_addresses/{ip['ip']}",
        headers={
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'x-apikey': db['token'],
        }
    ).json()['data']['attributes']
    for report in response:
        # date'] is a timestamp value, so I convert it to a date Y-m-d.
        date = date
        if thirty_days_ago <= date:
            requests_response_list.append({
                'ip': ip['ip'],
                'date': date,
            })
    db['time'] = now
    
    # use a round robin way to cycle throught the tokens.
    token_index = (token_index + 1) % len(dbs) # Move to the next token
    
    checked_ips.add(ip['ip'])
    sleep(5)


This should solve the OP’s problem. Just noting that if there are more than 5 tokens and the sleep interval is 5 seconds, you don’t actually need the elapsed time check, because each token is guaranteed not to be used more often than 5 * len(dbs) seconds.

Won't a continuous external counter solve your problem?
# ...

db_pos = -1
for ip in client_ips:
    for _ in dbs:
        db_pos += 1
        db_pos %= len(dbs)
        db = dbs[db_pos]
        # ...
        break

